# Flink MapState cleaning entire values for the map key during TTL Clean up

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a requirement to keep last 25 sec values in flink map state for each and every key, but TTL removes the entire values at once 25-sec reached. please see my code, in the code List holds the incoming data for each sensor id in every second, to reduce the memory storage, I have to retain only 25-sec data in  List is there any way to achieve that? TTL clearing the entire List.

```
public class ContinousDataProcessor
    extends   KeyedProcessFunction<String,SensorData,Tuple2<String,Integer>> {

private transient MapState<String, List<SensorData>> SensorValueMapState;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public void open(Configuration config) {
    MapStateDescriptor<String, List<SensorData>> varibaleTagValueMapDescriptor = new MapStateDescriptor(
            "variableTagValueMapState", String.class, SensorData.class);
    StateTtlConfig ttlConfig = StateTtlConfig.newBuilder(Time.seconds(25))
            .setUpdateType(StateTtlConfig.UpdateType.OnCreateAndWrite)
            .setStateVisibility(StateTtlConfig.StateVisibility.NeverReturnExpired).build();

    varibaleTagValueMapDescriptor.enableTimeToLive(ttlConfig);
    SensorValueMapState= getRuntimeContext().getMapState(varibaleTagValueMapDescriptor);

}

@Override
public void processElement(SensorData inputData, Context arg1, Collector arg2) throws Exception {


    if (SensorValueMapState.contains(inputData.sensorId)) {
        SensorValueMapState.get(inputData.sensorId).add(inputData);
    } else {
        List<SensorData> sensorDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        sensorDataList.add(inputData);
        SensorValueMapState.put(inputData.sensorId, sensorDataList);
    }

            for (SensorData str : SensorValueMapState.get(inputData.sensorId)) {

        System.out.println(str.eventTime);          
    }}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want TTL to be applied per each element in the list.
The list is a value in map state in your case. The map state has no insight about the structure of the user value in map state. This is a limitation of data layout in state backends. Therefore, applying TTL per each element is not possible in the current implementation.

The TTL is applied per user value in value state, per user element in list state and per user key/value pair in map state.

Depending on requirements of your application, you could try list state with a composite key:

```
key of KeyedProcessFunction = current key of your KeyedProcessFunction + your current map state key
```

This does not allow to easily obtain all lists by current key of your KeyedProcessFunction though as you can do it now.

Comment: Thanks azagrebin, in my case key of keyedprrocessfunction and key of mapstate is same. Can u advice how this composite key is going to fix this issue ?

Comment: If the key is the same (sensorId) then not sure why you need the map state because your map state will always have only one entry for each sensorId (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/stream/state/state.html#using-managed-keyed-state). If you use ListState<SensorData> instead then each element in there will expire with its own 25sec timeout and not the whole list at once. But ListState<SensorData> is not so flexible as java List, e.g. you cannot easily change/access each element by index.

Comment: ListState<SensorData> will be implicitly always created for each key of your keyedprrocessfunction as you always process inputData and have access to ListState<SensorData> with a certain key in processElement.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the  details. looks like my code snippet is little bit confuses your thoughts. Imagine a situation in which we are getting continous data from different sensors for different my company branches, in this case KEY of keyedprrocessfunction is BRNACHID and i have to create a MapState that contains Sensor Specific data in enery ten seconds for every branch. My Mapstate looks like <SENSORID, List<SENSOR DETAILS IN EVERY TEN SEC>>, I hope the scenario is clear now.  How can i use TTL in this sitaution to remove values from list values for each SensorId. Sorry for troubling you..

Comment: Ok, so the key is not the same in KeyedProcessFunction and MapState. Then I can only suggest what I already wrote in the main answer. The composite key would be (BRNACHID, SENSORID) in KeyedProcessFunction and MapState would be replaced by ListState<SENSOR DETAILS IN EVERY TEN SEC>. If you keep using MapState, TTL will apply to the entire List<SENSOR DETAILS IN EVERY TEN SEC>> because it is a blackbox java object for Flink without any internal TTLs per element. TTL is applied per Flink state entry.

Comment: Check also other types of Flink state, maybe some other would fit better to your application.